# Virtualenv does not change PYTHONPATH in Cronjob

Tags: python, cron, centos, virtualenv

Crontab code:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /var/www/envs/venv/myproj/scripts/send_hit.sh
```

.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/envs/venv
source bin/activate

echo $PYTHONPATH
echo $PATH
```

Output:

```
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>


/var/www/envs/venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

As you can see, the $PYTHONPATH is empty. However, it is really not when I activate it manually.

```
[root@server venv]# source bin/activate
(venv)[root@server venv]# echo $PYTHONPATH
:/var/www/envs/venv/myproj:/var/www/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: `bin/activate` does not update/set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (you can just grep the file). It only updates `PATH` to include env's `bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PYTHONPATH variable is not accessible from crontab. You should just set PYTHONPATH variable in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/envs/venv
source bin/activate

PYTHONPATH=/path/to/python
export PYTHONPATH

echo $PYTHONPATH
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab),

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner. HOME and SHELL may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME may not.

You should explicitly set `$PYTHONPATH` in either the crontab file or your script.

[This ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/a/337921) has a few methods of setting environment variables within cron.